# How do I get my discord.py bot to add a new member?

Tags: python, discord

I wanted that when I marked a user, the bot added him to the server, I already did something similar, but he only sent an invitation.

ps: I don't have a code example here to add the question, but my bot is in python

```
@bot.command
async def add_member(ctx, member: discord.Membrer):
    await guild.add_member(member)
```

what I just typed is a theoretical code, I don't know if these commands exist, it's just to illustrate the idea I had

Comment: My suspicion is that discord doesn't allow a bot to add a user to a server, as a spam prevention measure. (You can imagine a nefarious bot adding thousands of users to a spam server.) I don't think you can force somebody to join a discord server without them clicking an invite link

Comment: Got it, could use it in a harmful way, too bad, but thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't possible using the bot API. You'll need to make your target user go through the [OAuth2](https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/oauth2) flow with the scope `guilds.join`, after which you can use the [`/guilds/{guild.id}/members/{user.id}`](https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/guild#add-guild-member) endpoint with the token you will get to join a guild on a specific user's behalf.